# Movebase: robot move backwards when it detects an obstacle

Tags: ros, navigation, robot, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

What is the parameter that controls how far backwards the robot goes when it detects an obstacle at close proximity? Is it an issue related to the local planner or a setting in move_base?

Thanks

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
    # Robot Configuration Parameters
    acc_lim_x: 0.35        #was 0.5
    acc_lim_y: 0.35         #was 0.5
    acc_lim_theta: 0.35     #was 0.5
    max_vel_x: 0.35         #was 0.5
    min_vel_x: 0.05
    max_vel_theta: 1.0
    min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.05 #was0.4
    escape_vel: -0.06
    holonomic_robot: false

    # Goal Tolerance Parameters
    xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1 #was 0.3
    yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1 #was 0.3 lower means harder to achieve
    latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false
    path_distance_bias: 20.0 #default 0.6 - wasn't used - see pdist_scale
    goal_distance_bias: 0.8 #default 0.8 - wasn't used - see gdist_scale

    # Forward Simulation Parameters
    sim_time: 10.0
    sim_granularity: 0.025
    vx_samples: 5
    vtheta_samples: 20
    controller_frequency: 20.0 #has to be the same as in move_base.launch

    # Trajectory Scoring Parameters
    meter_scoring: true
    pdist_scale: 0.8
    gdist_scale: 0.6
    occdist_scale: 0.10 #was 0.01 
    heading_lookahead: 0.325 - was default 
    heading_scoring: false 
    dwa: false
    global_frame_id: odom

    # Oscillation Prevention Parameters
    oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
```

-->
  
    
  -->
  -->

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="$(arg base_global_planner)"/>
<param name="base_local_planner" value="$(arg base_local_planner)"/>  
<param name="recovery_behavior_enabled" value="true"/> 
<param name="recovery_behaviour_enabled" value="true"/> 
<param name="clearing_rotation_allowed" value="true"/>
<param name="controller_frequency" value="20.0"/> 
<param name="planner_patience" value="5.0"/>
<param name="planner_frequency" value="0.0"/>
<param name="controller_patience" value="15.0"/>

<!--<param name="oscillation_timeout" value="40"/> -->

<!-- Remap into namespace for cmd_vel_mux switching-->
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="/RosAria/cmd_vel" />
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230417/movebase:-robot-move-backwards-when-it-detects-an-obstacle/) by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Moving backwards is handled by base_local_planner. The speed that the robot backs up at is set by escape_vel parameter.

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2020-09-11**:
What's the parameter/setting that specifies *how far* backwards though?